# Installing Chromedriver on Ubuntu to use Splinter

Tags: python, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium, splinter

I am trying the use the Splinter library for Python to run testing of web pages. The problem is that I cannot get the location of the chromedriver executable to be correct. Everytime I try and run a file I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "autoCookie.py", line 7, in <module>
browser = Browser('chrome')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 44, in Browser
return driver(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/chrome.py", line 23, in __init__
self.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 68, in start
and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.                 Please download from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list                and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

I have changed the directory to every location suggested on the web, I ran through the installation process on the splinter website, I tried setting it using os.environ, I have edited the code in the webdrive.py file inside the selenium folder, I have tried literally everything I can find on the internet and still I get this error. Also, the program runs correctly when I run it with browser = Browser("firefox"), however as soon as I get to the click() function it exits with an error. But that's a different problem I would prefer to just get it working in Chrome. I am open to any suggestions I'm just hoping someone on here will be able to help me out. Thanks in advance!

Other information:

OS: Ubuntu 13.04, Python 2.7, Selenium 2.36.0, chromedriver_linux64

Answer (score 0):

What is your PYTHONPATH and PATH set to?

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
>>> sys.path
```

Where is your ChromeDriver executable?  It needs to be in one of the directories returned above.